# Get friends of a User using Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am facing a problem in fetching the friends of a user. The following code is working fine when "me" is passed as an UID. But it doesn't work when a user id is passed like 523621551. Every thing is set in the permissions. And i get the "Unsupported operation" error. Following is the code.

```
public function getAllFriends($uid) {
        return $this->fb->api("/" . $uid . "/friends", 'GET', array(
                    'access_token' => $this->fb->getAccessToken())
        );
}
```

So, what is causing this problem?
I also studied other related questions but those didn't help. :(

Comment: Try doing it within the Graph API explorer with your access token etc... https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Answer (score 3):

You can´t get the friends of ANY user, you can only get the friends of the user who is authorized at the moment. The docs are a bit misleading, it may only work with the (app scoped) user id of the authorized user, but it will never work with any other user id - that request is "unsupported" ;)

Also, you can only get the users who authorized the same App too, just in case you don´t know yet. See changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

---

**Edit**: I just tested it with an App Scoped ID in the API Explorer and it works, so i assume you are trying to get the friends of another user as i expected - which is not supported, of course.

I also tested it with the "real" ID of the authorized user and got the following error:

> The global ID 1603196280 is not allowed. Please use the application
>   specific ID instead.

Makes sense, you would not get the global ID in the App anyway, only App Scoped IDs. As i said, the error you get is not very clear but correct: Getting the friends of ANY user is "unsupported".

Comment: He said that `everything is set in the permissions`

Comment: suppose if a user didn't allow anyone to see his friends then there should be some other error. But it is "Unsupported operation" error.

Comment: getting the friends of ANY user is just not possible. that´s not an authorization issue, that´s just how it is. but i would not count on always getting perfect error messages ;)

Comment: btw, what user id is it? the user id of the authorized user? app scoped or real?

Comment: I'm not sure that it would return "Unsupported operation" if it was an issue with the access token...

Comment: it is not really an issue with the access token. that call just never makes sense, because it would only work with the id of the authorized user, and you can always use /me/friends.

Comment: Of course it makes sense... why doesn't it make sense???  It's here plain and clear in the docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/user/friends

Comment: read my answer, i said "the docs are bit misleading". it´s not always 100% as it is written in some docs, you know ;) - anyway, for me it makes sense to get "unsupported get request" - because it does not make sense to make the friend call with anyone else except for "/me".

Comment: just did some testing in the api explorer, my answer must be correct. see the edited part of it.